# Android Studio: ImageManager get image from web

Tags: android, google-api

When I use this code it just covers the ImageLoadedListener with red and says it does not recognize such a method. This is my very first time using ImageMager so if you could tell me what is wrong and may be give me a sample code, from which I can check the usage of ImageManager. Also is there a way to safe the image on the device and then with a string or an int(for R.id.drawable) get the image in future references?

```
 ImageView iv;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageManager imageManager;

        URI uri;
        try {
             uri = new URI("http://suburban-k9.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/small-dog-sydrome-300x300.jpg");


        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            uri=null;
        }
        Context context = getApplication().getApplicationContext();
        imageManager = ImageManager.create(context);

        Log.v("app", "LoadImageFromGoogle Manager created for Image #" + id);

        imageManager.loadImage(new OnImageLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageLoaded(Uri uri, Drawable drawable, boolean b) {

                    Log.v("app", "LoadImageFromGoogle Image loaded #" + id);

                    myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


                    Log.v("app", "LoadImageFromGoogle Image added #" + id);
                } 

        },uri,android.R.drawable.btn_default);


iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: How do you import ImageManager?

Comment: import com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager;